# Call MATLAB function with original name even when its function M file is named differently?

Tags: function, matlab

New to MATLAB. At work, in the vast set of MATLAB functions we have, I have noticed that some function `m` files (a file that declares and defines one single function) contain a function that has a different name, e.g. `myfunction.m` contains `yourfunction()`. From what I know it is not a must for both to be the same but it is considered a good practice.

This creates a problem, since even in MATLAB editor I have to call `myfunction()` in the command line instead of `yourfunction()`.

Does MATLAB provide some way to enable me to still call `yourfunction()` (the actual name of the function) even with that discrepancy in naming?

Comment: If you insist on using a different name than the file name, you could always use an anonymous function that maps to the file name. E.g., yourfunction = @myfunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Matlab, each m file can contain only one function that is accessible from outside the file. That function is defined at the top of the m file.

The function is called by the same name as m file name, even if the function name is different from the file. Although more than one function can exist in the same m file but all other functions that exist in that file are visible to only to the function defined at the top of m file. It like scope of the other functions is only inside the m file.

You can use aliasing to assign more than one name to a matlab function.
`yourfunction = @myfunction`. The downside is you have to write the aliasing syntax separately in a scrip or run on command window, but it cannot be included in the same m file.

Comment: I can do that. However, I don't see the point, since the wrapper code generator I have created (in bash :D) already extracts everything incl. file name, return values, declared function name and arguments to create code that loads a namespace instead of directly calling the underlying function. Since the generated code is per function (meaning it only calls the top declared function and no nested ones), an alias is just an extra, albeit an easy one, step that makes no sense in my context. Thank you.